# Display dropdownlist filter data?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'SRF_STUDENT_ID')->dropdownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map(StudentDetails::find()->all(),'STUDENT_REGISTRATION_ID','STUDENT_REGISTRATION_ID'),
                    ['prompt'=>'Select Student Id']); ?>
```

how to set where condition in the dropdownlist. i want **select STUDENT_REGISTRATION_ID from StudentDetails where is_select = 0;** data result set dropdownlist. please give me your help.

Comment: Use `StudentDetails::find()->where(['is_select' => 0])->all()`.

Comment: Thankq so much @Insane Skull. It's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'SRF_STUDENT_ID')->dropdownList(
                 ArrayHelper::map(StudentDetails::find()->where(['is_select' => 0])->all(),'STUDENT_REGISTRATION_ID','STUDENT_REGISTRATION_ID'),
                ['prompt'=>'Select Student Id']); ?>
```

Comment: please i want to help. how to add this "['ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1']";

Comment: @PrabuddhaNamal.  add `orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])` and for limit 1 you can use `one()` instead of `all()` or `limit(1)`.

Comment: Thank You so mach @Insane Skull.

Comment: please again me help. @Insane Skull i want id parameter please gave me id parameter . "http://localhost/YII2/Sky_test/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=parent-details%2Fcreate&id=xcvx" 
I'm try this code but not working.
(ex : $id=Yii::$app->request->getParams('id'))

Comment: @PrabuddhaNamal.  are you trying to get id in controller? [Yii chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99406/yii-warriors)

Comment: how do this ? please gave me example ?       this is controller parameter pass.                                                     public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new StudentDetails();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            return $this->redirect(['parent-details/create', 'id' => $model->STUDENT_REGISTRATION_ID]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

Comment: @PrabuddhaNamal. Better ask new question.

Comment: please give me example ? i try to parameter pass _form page.are You understand me.

Comment: @PrabuddhaNamal. Show your `create.php`.

Comment: Are you looked for this.

Comment: Sorry. i can't be new questions ask. so . I'm having a problem on the jasper report call. how to call this jasper report. please give me a video link. yiiframework.com/extension/yiijasper. I looked this but I didn't get it.